# Network tool to monitor IP packet fragmentation

Tags: networking, ip

Is there a tool, similar to `iptraf`, that would let me see how many incoming/outgoing IP packets get fragmented/defragmented, and what percent of traffic they are? I know this can be counted with the `iptables` [u32 module](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-3.html#ss3.21), but maybe there is something more user friendly.

Comment: `netstat -s` gives you some statistics. Note that fragmentation is often offloaded to the NIC.

Comment: I know about the offloading, but this happens in the hardware, right? I'm investigating network load on the CPU. `netstat -s` is almost perfect, it does not differentiate outgoing/incoming packets.